# 389 Directory server testing with lib389

Tags: python, linux, pytest, openldap

I am testing 389 Directory server testing with  lib389.

I am following the bellow link.

https://fedorapeople.org/~spichugi/html/guidelines.html#add-modify-and-delete-operations

```
 from lib389._constants import *

# Add an entry
USER_DN = 'cn=mreynolds,{}'.format(DEFAULT_SUFFIX)
standalone.add_s(Entry((USER_DN, {
                          'objectclass': (b'top', b'person'),
                          'cn': b'mreynolds',
                          'sn': b'reynolds',
                          'userpassword': b'password'
                      })))

 # Modify an entry
 standalone.modify_s(USER_DN, [(ldap.MOD_REPLACE, 'cn', b'Mark Reynolds')])

 # Delete an entry
 standalone.delete_s(USER_DN)
```

What is the meaning of "standalone" here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its the name of ldap server instance:

```
 import ldap
 standalone=ldap.open('ldap-server-name')
```